# angularjs $broadcast not reflecting values on view

Tags: angularjs, angular-broadcast

When I add a $broadcast in $rootScope and catch it to other controller, it is not reflecting any value to view.
Example:

```js
// on first ctrl.
controller('firstCtrl', ['$scope','$location', '$rootScope', function($scope, $location, $rootScope) {
    $scope.myFunc = function() { 
        $rootScope.$broadcast('someEvent');
        $location.path('/users');
    }
}])


// On Users Page.
.controller('usersCtrl', ['$scope','$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) { 
    $scope.dataFilter = {};
    $rootScope.$on('someEvent', function(event, b) {
        $scope.callOnBroadcast();
    });
  
    // call this function on broadcast.  
    $scope.callOnBroadcast = function() {
      $scope.dataFilter = {
        types: [
          {key: 'tags',     val: 'Collections'},
          {key: 'prices',   val: 'Price'},
          {key: 'ratings',  val: 'Rating'},
          {key: 'designers',val: 'Designer'}
        ],
        data: {tags: [], prices: [], ratings: [], designers: []}

      };

      $scope.$apply();


    };
}])
```

```html
<h4 data-ng-repeat="ftr in dataFilter.types">  
  {{ftr.val}}
</h4>
```

When I Use `MyFunc` function on `firstCtrl`, it will redirect me to user's page, also broadcast function run. 
On users page, I Use `$scope.callOnBroadcast()` when broadcast is on, but it is reflecting any change on view page even I use `$scope.$apply()`.
Where am I wrong ?

Comment: do `$rootScope$broadcast('someEvent');` if controller hierarchy is not there..Please add html to see how your controller hierarchy

Comment: here is no controllers hierarchy, that is why I added $broadcast in $rootScope.

Comment: oh sorry its a copy paste mistake. I already use $broadcast in $roootScope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your both the controller don't have any hierarchy that's why you need to $broadcast the event in `$rootScope` rather than scope,

> Your problem is you are broadcasting event before registering listener
>   event. After that you are doing `$location.path('/users')`, which load
>   user template with `usersCtrl`.

I think you should do redirection 1st and then broadcast the event in `$rootScope` with certain `timeout` inorder to make available the `usersCtrl`

**Code**

```
// on first ctrl.
controller('firstCtrl', ['$scope','$location', '$rootScope',  '$timeout',function($scope, $location, $rootScope, $timeout) {
    $scope.myFunc = function() { 
        $location.path('/users');
        $timeout(function(){
          //boardcast will available to every listener
          $rootScope.$broadcast('someEvent'); 
        },1000);
    }
}]);
```

> Make sure the other listener code should be register before
>   broadcasting the event.(Below listener should be registered before
>   broadcasting).

```
$scope.$on('someEvent', function(event, b) {
    $scope.callOnBroadcast();
});
```

> For making it more better solution, you could use resolve of
>   `$routeProvider`

Comment: could you please confirm that controller has been loaded or not before broadcasting event

Comment: yes controller is loading and if I add alert in '$scope.callOnBroadcast()', It is reflecting.

Comment: @Rajeev no...your code clearly says that you are broadcasting event then doing `$location.path('/users');` which is wrong..do `$location.path('/users');` first and then do braodcast

Comment: I updated my code like you mentioned above but it is not working.

Comment: So basically the issue was that your controller wasn't instantiated :)

Just giving it a second to load before you broadcast is the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this "How Scope.$broadcast() Interacts With Isolate Scopes In AngularJS" 
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2725-how-scope-broadcast-interacts-with-isolate-scopes-in-angularjs.htm

It will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject $rootScope into your controllers and broadcast on that level.
You can see the $broadcast taking effect here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/ySrEU4accdgeY7iJhdZi?p=preview

```
app.controller('firstCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope','$location', function($scope, $rootScope, $location) {
$scope.myFunc = function() { 
    $rootScope.$broadcast('someEvent');
    $location.path('/users');
};

}])


// On Users Page.
.controller('usersCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) { 
$scope.dataFilter;
$rootScope.$on('someEvent', function(event, b) {
    $scope.callOnBroadcast();
    //$scope.dataFilter = 'test';
});

// call this function on broadcast.  
$scope.callOnBroadcast = function() {
  $scope.dataFilter = {
    types: [
      {key: 'tags',     val: 'Collections'},
      {key: 'prices',   val: 'Price'},
      {key: 'ratings',  val: 'Rating'},
      {key: 'designers',val: 'Designer'}
    ],
    data: {tags: [], prices: [], ratings: [], designers: []}

  };

  //$scope.$apply();  <- I don't think is necessary


};
```

}])

Comment: The code is working if I use $rootScope.dataFilter instead of $scope.dataFilter. I don't know why this happen. As view has  "usersCtrl", so their is no need to add $rootScope.

Comment: Just to confirm - the usersCtrl is already instantiated when you call the function, right?

Comment: right, ctrl instantiated first and then function call